# How to update prop values in Child class component when Parent class component state is changed? : React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-props

I have a parent class component called CardView.js which contains a child class component called Tab.js (which contains a FlatList).

When a button is pressed in CardView.js, a modal appears with various options. A user chooses an option and presses 'OK' on the modal. At this point the onOKHandler method in the parent component updates the parent state (`tabOrderBy: orderBy` and  `orderSetByModal: true`). NOTE: These two pieces of state are passed to the child component as props.

**Here is what I need:**

When the onOKHandler is pressed in the parent, I need the child component to re-render with it's props values reflecting the new state values in the parent state. NOTE: I do not want the Parent Component to re-render as well.

At the moment when onOKHandler is pressed, the child component reloads, but it's props are still showing the OLD state from the parent.

**Here is what I have tried:**

- When the onOKHandler is pressed, I use setState to update the parent state and then I use the setState callback to call a method in the child to reload the child. The child reloads but its  props are not updated.
- I have tried using componentDidUpdate in the child which checks when the prop `orderSetByModal` is changed. This does not work at all.

I have tried many of the recommendations in other posts like this - nothing works! Where am I going wrong please? Code is below:

Parent Component: CardView.js

```
import React from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import { Windows} from "../stores";
import { TabView, SceneMap } from "react-native-tab-view";
import { Tab, TabBar, Sortby } from "../components";

class CardView extends React.Component {
  state = {    
    level: 0,
    tabIndex: 0,
    tabRoutes: [],
    recordId: null,    
    renderScene: () => {},
    showSortby: false,  
    orderSetByModal: false, 
    tabOrderBy: ''   
  };

  tabRefs = {}; 

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.reload(this.props.windowId, null, this.state.level, this.state.tabIndex);     
  };

  reload = (windowId, recordId, level, tabIndex) => {     
    this.setState({ recordId, level, tabIndex });
    const tabRoutes = Windows.getTabRoutes(windowId, level);      
    this.setState({ tabRoutes });    
    const sceneMap = {};   
    this.setState({ renderScene: SceneMap(sceneMap)});    
  
    for (let i = 0; i < tabRoutes.length; i++) {
      const tabRoute = tabRoutes[i];          
      sceneMap[tabRoute.key] = () => {        
        return (
          <Tab
            onRef={(ref) => (this.child = ref)}
            ref={(tab) => (this.tabRefs[i] = tab)}
            windowId={windowId}           
            tabSequence={tabRoute.key}
            tabLevel={level}
            tabKey={tabRoute.key}
            recordId={recordId}                               
            orderSetByModal={this.state.orderSetByModal}            
            tabOrderBy={this.state.tabOrderBy}
          ></Tab>
        );
      };    
    }    
  };
 
  startSortByHandler = () => {
    this.setState({showSortby: true});    
  };

  endSortByHandler = () => {
    this.setState({ showSortby: false});    
  }; 

  orderByFromModal = () => {   
    return 'creationDate asc' 
  }

  refreshTab = () => {
    this.orderByFromModal();
    this.child.refresh() 
  }

  onOKHandler = () => {
    this.endSortByHandler();   
    const orderBy = this.orderByFromModal();    
    this.setState({     
      tabOrderBy: orderBy, 
      orderSetByModal: true}, () => {         
      this.refreshTab()        
    });        
  }

  render() {    
    return (      
      <View>         
        <TabView
          navigationState={{index: this.state.tabIndex, routes: this.state.tabRoutes}}
          renderScene={this.state.renderScene}
          onIndexChange={(index) => {          
            this.setState({ tabIndex: index });            
          }}
          lazy
          swipeEnabled={false}         
          renderTabBar={(props) => <TabBar {...props} />}
        />       
        <Sortby
          visible={this.state.showSortby}
          onCancel={this.endSortByHandler}          
          onOK={this.onOKHandler}                
        ></Sortby>        
      </View>   
    );
  }
}

export default CardView;
```

Child Component: Tab.js

```
import React from "react";
import { FlatList } from "react-native";
import { Windows } from "../stores";
import SwipeableCard from "./SwipeableCard";

class Tab extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentTab: null,
      records: [],
      refreshing: false,
    };
    this.listRef = null;
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onRef(this);
    await this.reload(this.props.recordId, this.props.tabLevel, this.props.tabSequence);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.onRef(null);
  }

  //I tried adding componentDidUpdate, but it did not work at all
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.orderSetByModal !== prevProps.orderSetByModal) {
      this.refresh();
    }
  }

  getOrderBy = () => {
    let orderByClause;
    if (this.props.orderSetByModal) {
      orderByClause = this.props.tabOrderBy;
    } else {
      orderByClause = "organization desc";
    }
    return orderByClause;
  };

  async reload() {
    const currentTab = Windows.getTab(this.props.windowId, this.props.tabSequence, this.props.tabLevel);
    this.setState({ currentTab });
    let response = null;
    const orderBy = this.getOrderBy();
    response = await this.props.entity.api.obtainRange(orderBy);
    this.setState({ records: response.dataList })
  }

  refresh = () => {
    this.setState({ refreshing: true }, () => {
      this.reload(this.props.recordId, this.props.tabLevel, this.props.tabSequence)
      .then(() => this.setState({ refreshing: false }));
    });
  };

  renderTabItem = ({ item, index }) => (
    <SwipeableCard
      title={"Card"}      
    />
  );

  render() {
    if (!this.state.currentTab) {
      return null;
    }
    
    return (
      <>
        <FlatList
          ref={(ref) => (this.listRef = ref)}
          style={{ paddingTop: 8 }}
          refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
          onRefresh={this.refresh}
          data={this.state.records}
          keyExtractor={(item) => (item.isNew ? "new" : item.id)}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Tab;
```